# MERN Stack: How to prevent a User from registering (being added to an array) multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

Semi-new developer building a project using the MERN stack.

The app has two models, one for `Users` and one for `Tournaments`.  Tournament model has an attribute called `participants` which is an array.

I wrote an Express backend route so that a User can register for Tournaments.participants[].
This looks like:

```
router.post('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Tournament.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(tournament => {
            tournament.participants.push(req.body);
            return tournament.save();
        })
        .then(savedTournament => res.json(savedTournament))
        .catch(err => res.json(err));
});
```

However, a User can just keep clicking Sign Up and I'd have a bunch of duplicate users, so I'm trying to write a conditional that will disable Sign Up if the user is already in Tournament.participants[].

I tried writing a conditional inside the Express route using `Array.includes(req.body)` but couldn't hack it.
Looked something like

```
Tournament.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(tournament => {
            if (tournament.participants.includes(req.body) {
              return res.status(400).json({ msg: "This user already signed up for this tournament" });
            } else {
              tournament.participants.push(req.body);
              return tournament.save();
            }
        })
        .then(savedTournament => res.json(savedTournament))
        .catch(err => res.json(err));
```

I tried different variations as well, like `if (tournament.participants.includes(!req.body))` then push(req.body), etc.

And I also tried just rendering a different button if the `participants.includes(user)` but I believe this should be done on the backend anyway.. I'm open to suggestions.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Use some `id` of the user, rather than checking if the whole object is `include`d

Comment: What do you send in `req.body`? Can you add to the question? Also Tournament schema and a sample document would be good.

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61351906/mern-added-a-user-object-to-another-models-array-prevented-duplicate-addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't use the native comparison operators with objects, `includes` included:

```js
const foo = { id: 1 };
const bar = [{ id: 1 }];
console.log(bar.includes(foo)); // outputs `false`
```

You should use some kind of item `id` in order to check if its already exists:

```js
function isIdIncluded(arr, id) {
  return arr.some(x => x.id === id) 
}

const foo = { id: 1 };
const bar = [{ id: 1 }];
console.log(isIdIncluded(bar, 1)); // outputs `true`
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for slow reply.  Working a lot these days.
So using your suggestion, I got it to work partially.
A user signs up for a tournament, and if they try again, they get blocked.

What isn't working is, when I log out of that user and log in as a different user, it actually blocks that user also.

That might be a problem with how my redux state is managed..

But both users can create Tournaments, and their respective IDs/user attributes are correct. SO it doesn't make sense yet.

Comment: Sometimes it lets me submit multiple user submissions, and changes
_id
to
id

Comment: @DustinCintron If your property is named **either** `id` or `_id` then you should check both of them inside `isIdIncluded`: `[x.id, x._id].includes(id)`

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61351906/mern-added-a-user-object-to-another-models-array-prevented-duplicate-addition

Comment: Hey GalAbra.  I didn't quite understand your comment exactly, so I used the && operator in my isIdIncluded.  Something like isIdIncluded(arr, id) !== false && isIdIncluded(arr, _id) !== false
It's preventing a User from signing up twice.  BUT it's preventing other users from signing up

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are keeping the users's _id in the `participants` array, and your tournament schema is similar to this:

```js
const tournamentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  participants: Array,
});
```

Now if you send a request with this body:

```
{
    "user": "5e97255a342f395774f30162"  //the user id who wants to participate
}
```

You can use this code (I just changed the `req.body` to `req.body.user`)

```js
  Tournament.findById(req.params.id)
    .then((tournament) => {
      if (tournament.participants.includes(req.body.user)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "This user already signed up for this tournament" });
      } else {
        tournament.participants.push(req.body.user);
        return tournament.save();
      }
    })
    .then((savedTournament) => res.json(savedTournament))
    .catch((err) => res.status(500).json(err));
```

Now when a user first time participates a tournament, the document will be like this:

```
{
    "participants": [
        "5e97255a342f395774f30162"
    ],
    "_id": "5e97255a342f395774f30161",
    "name": "Chess Tournament"
}
```

And when the same user tries, the response will be like this with a 400 status code.

```
{
    "msg": "This user already signed up for this tournament"
}
```

Also please note that, the user id shouldn't be send in the request body, but it must be the user's id who is logged in.

Comment: Hi, this comment is helpful.  I'm getting closer to having this working.. but i'm confused about what you said.
You said my request could be
`{ "user": "asdfasdf"}` as in user, id

But on the bottom you said the user's ID shouldn't be passed in the req.body?